# Tool for response time analysis on JBoss server?

Tags: tomcat, jboss

I am running a pretty high traffic cluster of JBoss servers serving REST requests and I am interested in tools reading the access logs in Tomcat format (with %D parameter) to provide a detailed analysis of the response time on a per-call basis.
Ideally this tool would generate a chart showing the progression of the response time throughout the day, hour per hour, then a weekly view with averages on the day, and monthly with average on the weeks (CACTI style).

I've looked for such tools and couldn't find anything. Is any of you guys aware of something close to that before I start writing my own? I haven't looked into CACTI extensions yet, but that be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com) can read Tomcat's Log4J format. They seem to have built-in support for the following template:

```
2005-03-07 16:44:03,110 53223013 [PoolThread-0] INFO [STDOUT] got some property...
```

I think the date-time in the above pattern matches the `%d` ISO8601 default format.

Splunk's reporting facilities were pretty nice a year ago; the free version started getting scaled back around that point, so if cost is an option this may not be a good choice.

There are some potential Splunk competitors listed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183977/what-commercial-and-open-source-competitors-are-there-to-splunk), which gives you some additional options. Again, I am not sure there is a good no-cost option in this space.

Answer (score 1):

[AwStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is quite handy open source tool to read access logs of the Apache / Tomcat log format. You can customize the log format to pass into the tool and it will give you cumulative reports with drill down for each response line from the log.

See the [demo screenshots](http://www.nltechno.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=destailleur.fr) here for an idea.